# Plotting problem of spectra: wavelength v Intensity

Tags: python, plot

I have a spectra of 29 order, 25 observations and 1973 pixels (columns). The original code has been cleaned of bad observations hence the reduction from 2047 to 1973.   Ive been trying to plot one order (say order 13 of 29) with an overlay of 25 observations (Tw v Tint), matching the wavelength the order relates to.  The code is linked to another code which loads all the data called "Prepare.mat", I have double checked all the info in this code, so Im pretty sure its okay, it loads the spectra without any analysis.   The original code has been adapted from matlab.  The code that is having the issues is the one below, Im sure I has something to do with the matching and permuting, it plots all sorts of weird and strange things.  Can anyone spot where I am going wrong here?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
from scipy.io import loadmat, savemat
from scipy.signal import medfilt
import scipy.io
import scipy.io as sio
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib widget

def shift_vel(wave, vel):
    c = 299792458  # speed of light in m/s
    shift = np.log(1 + vel / c)
    wave = np.exp(np.log(wave) - shift)
    return wave

# Specify the path to the "Prep.mat" file
prepared_mat_file_path = '/Users/XXX/Desktop/Star/Prep.mat'

# Load data from the "Prepared.mat" file
prepared_data = sio.loadmat(prepared_mat_file_path)

# Specify the path to the HDF5 file
hdf5_file_path = '/Users/XXX/Desktop/Star/bcorr_fib4_all.mat'

# Open the HDF5 file for reading
with h5py.File(hdf5_file_path, 'r') as hdf5_file:
    # Access the dataset you want
    bcorr_fib4_all = hdf5_file['bcorr_fib4_all'][:]

    
# Access to the data from "Prep.mat"
ALLfib4spec = prepared_data['ALLfib4spec']
nALLfib4specbNc = prepared_data['nALLfib4specbNc']
ALLfib4specwave = prepared_data['ALLfib4specwave']

num_pixels = 1973
num_observations = 25
num_orders = 183

# Generate some example data (replace with your actual data)
wave = np.random.rand(num_orders, num_pixels)
bcorr_fib4_all = np.random.rand(num_observations)


# Barycentric correction

# Initialize ALLwv with the appropriate dimensions
ALLwv = np.zeros((num_orders, num_pixels, num_observations))

for s in range(ALLfib4spec.shape[2]):
    tWVout = ALLfib4specwave[:,:,s]
    for ord in range(tWVout.shape[0]):
        tWVout[ord,:] = shift_vel(tWVout[ord,:], bcorr_fib4_all[s]*-1)
    # dimensions are: [orders pixels observations]
    ALLwv[0:tWVout.shape[0], :, s] = tWVout  # Assign values to the corresponding orders in ALLwv
        
        
# Define an order (13) to analyze and reshape the 3D data to 2D data of just that order
Tw = np.transpose(ALLwv[12, :, :])  # MATLAB indices are 1-based
Tint = np.transpose(nALLfib4specbNc[12, :, :])  # MATLAB indices are 1-based

Tw = np.random.rand(1973, 25) 

# Create the log step wavelength axis so each pixel is the same velocity size
c = 299792458  # speed of light in m/s
logstep = 1e-6  # step size in log-wavelength space
a = 8  # number near our wavelength in log space (log(wavelength) ~ 8)

#Plotting
# Assuming Tw and Tint have been loaded or generated correctly
order_to_plot = 12  #Python uses 0-based indexing, so order 13

# Extract the wavelength and intensity data for the chosen order
wavelength_order = Tw
intensity_order = Tint[:, order_to_plot]  # Extract intensity for the chosen order

# Create a figure and axis for the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.title(f'Order {order_to_plot + 1} - Wavelength vs. Intensity')

# Loop through the 25 observations and plot them
for observation in range(25):
    plt.plot(wavelength_order, intensity_order[:, observation], label=f'Observation {observation + 1}')

# Add labels and legend
plt.xlabel('Wavelength')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```